# How to configure php libmysqlclient.so lookup directory

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I've just created [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org) system with PHP and MySQL.
After doing php -v i saw:

```
Cannot open libmysqlclient.so.16 (...)
```

I checked under

```
/usr/lib/
```

There was no `libmysqlclient.so.16`, but it was under:

```
/usr/lib/mysql/
```

I created a symlink in:

```
/usr/lib/
```

And everything started to work.

But now I looked into my host system and there is no symlink, however PHP works.

Where can I set parameter to `./configure` saying where to look for `libmysqlclient`?

Comment: Can you say which OS Distro do you use?
Also would you question be better under Server Fault ;)

Comment: on my target os I'm using buildroot, on my host - gentoo, but there everything is fine

Comment: I have misread the whole Question, if you want to build it 
with `configure` try this option:

`--with-libdir=lib64`

Or when you build `mysql` from source, you could say that it should 
install it in `/usr/local`?